# Oracle: How do I retrieve the table name when using select all with multiple joins

Tags: oracle, pdo

I have a query with lots of joins, bringing my total column count to over 1000. To get around this limitation, I need to use select * instead of manually defining the aliases.

I want to do

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table0 t0
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON         t0.field = t1.field
WHERE      rownum < 10
```

In my results, I need to have the following defined in my column names

```
t0.column
t0.column2
t1.column
t1.column2
```

Is there a concept or technology that I'm missing to allow for this? I dont really want to rely on field order as it may change.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
SELECT t0.column, t0.column2, t1.column, t1.column2, t0.*, t1.* 
FROM      table0 t0
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON         t0.lm_mst_uid = t1.lm_mst_uid
WHERE      rownum < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    t0.*, t1.*
FROM      table0 t0
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON         t0.lm_mst_uid = t1.lm_mst_uid
WHERE      rownum < 10
```

Comment: I was hoping that something like this would work, however this just returns the column names and doesnt specify which table they came from.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can put a hint:

```
SELECT t1.*, 't1 <-> t2' , t2.*,  't2 <-> t3', t3.*
```

Now you end up seeing something like this:

```
 t1...................................|           | t2................|           | t3.....................|
 01-02-2012 | ... | More data from t1 | t1 <-> t2 | Some data from t2 | t2 <-> t3 | Now data from t3 | ... |
 01-02-2012 | ... | More data from t1 | t1 <-> t2 | Some data from t2 | t2 <-> t3 | Now data from t3 | ... |
 01-02-2012 | ... | More data from t1 | t1 <-> t2 | Some data from t2 | t2 <-> t3 | Now data from t3 | ... |
 01-02-2012 | ... | More data from t1 | t1 <-> t2 | Some data from t2 | t2 <-> t3 | Now data from t3 | ... |
 01-02-2012 | ... | More data from t1 | t1 <-> t2 | Some data from t2 | t2 <-> t3 | Now data from t3 | ... |
 01-02-2012 | ... | More data from t1 | t1 <-> t2 | Some data from t2 | t2 <-> t3 | Now data from t3 | ... |
```

And you know that everything between those marks `'t1 <-> t2'` belong to a table.